# Passing a Delphi record type to VB6 DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, com, vb6, ole

**VB6 DLL**

I have written a VB6 DLL which includes the following user-defined type (UDT), consisting only of primitive data types...

```
Public Type MyResults
  Result1 As Double
  Result2 As Double
  Result3 As Double
  Result4 As Double
  Result5 As Double
End Type
```

...and the following method...

```
Public Sub Method1(ByRef Results As Variant)
  Dim myRes As MyResults
  myRes = Results
  MsgBox "MyResults.Result1: " & myRes.Result1
  ...
End Sub
```

**Delphi Test Harness**

I have also written a test harness in Delphi and have created an equivalent Delphi record type to mimic the VB UDT, which is defined as follows...

```
TMyResults = packed record
  Result1: Double;
  Result2: Double;
  Result3: Double;
  Result4: Double;
  Result5: Double;
end;
```

From Delphi, I would like to call Method1 in the VB6 DLL and pass a variable of this type as an argument, so that VB can interpret it as an equivalent "type". So far, I have tried the following Delphi call...

```
procedure TMyApp.CallMethod1FromVBDLL(var MyResults: TMyResults);
var
  results: OleVariant;
  dll: Variant;
begin
  results := RecToVariant(MyResults, SizeOf(MyResults));
  dll := CreateOleObject('ApplicationName.ClassName');
  dll.Method1(results);
  ...
end;
```

...which uses the following function (source: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/2c/462130.html) to convert a record to a variant...

```
function TMyApp.RecToVariant(var AR; ARecSize: Integer): Variant;
var
  p: Pointer;
begin
  Result := VarArrayCreate([1, ARecSize], varByte);
  p := VarArrayLock(Result);
  try
    Move(AR, p^, ARecSize);
  finally
    VarArrayUnLock(Result); 
  end;
end;
```

An `EOleException` is reported back to Delphi due to a `Type mismatch` on the `myRes = Results` line in Method1 of the DLL.

Am I preparing and passing the argument correctly in Delphi?
How should I be using the argument in VB6?

Any assistance/advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this? Can't VB export functions that use UDTs?

Comment: If I change the Method1 argument from Variant to MyResults in VB and pass an argument of type TMyResults from Delphi, I get a "Type not allowed in Variant Dispatch call" error when compiling my test harness. So I concluded that I needed to pass an OleVariant instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your Delphi code is creating an `OleVariant` that contains a byte array (Automation type `VT_UI1 or VT_ARRAY`), which is not what VB is expecting.  It is expecting a UDT record (Automation type `VT_RECORD`) instead.

MSDN has an article explaining how to pass a UDT inside a Variant:

[Passing UDTs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221453.aspx)

> To pass single UDTs or safearrays of UDTs for late binding, the Automation client must have the information necessary to store the type information of the UDT into a VARIANT (and if late-binding, the UDT must be self-described). A VARIANT of type VT_RECORD wraps a RecordInfo object, which contains the necessary information about the UDT and a pointer the UDT itself. The RecordInfo object implements a new interface, IRecordInfo, for access to the information. It is important to know that the actual storage of the UDT is never owned by the VARIANT; the IRecordInfo pointer is the only thing that is owned by the VARIANT.
>
> The data for a UDT includes an IRecordInfo pointer to the description of the UDT, pRecInfo, and a pointer to the data, pvRecord.

In other words, you need to create a class that implements the [`IRecordInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221039.aspx) interface and wraps your actual record data, then you can store an instance of that class inside the `OleVariant` using the `VT_RECORD` type.  That will provide both COM and VB with the necessary metadata to marshal and access your record data.

Comment: You can also [get an instance of `IRecordInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221025(v=vs.85).aspx) from a type library (or [from an already loaded type library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221404.aspx)).  Easier, less tedious and less error-prone than implementing it yourself.